# menu_tree_all_data returning empty arrays for custom menus

Tags: 6, routes

I have tried to get the menu tree for two different custom menus using menu_tree_all_data, but they have returned empty arrays, while using it to get 'navigation' menu works.

Does anyone have any idea about what might be going on?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to print a menu tree, then it's answered [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130202051715/http://www.anilsagar.com/tips/drupal-tips/how-print-menu-tree-using-php-code-drupal-6). I have tried this and solution worked !

```
<?php

$tree = menu_tree_page_data('menu-name'); // Replace menu-name with menu name you want to print
$first_level = db_query("SELECT mlid FROM {menu_links} where menu_name = 'menu-name' and plid = 0 ORDER BY weight ASC");
while ($item = db_fetch_object($first_level)) {
  $mlid = $item->mlid;
  // Extract subtree
  $subtree = admin_console_menu_get_subtree($tree, $mlid);
  // Render as HTML menu list
  $content .= menu_tree_output($subtree);
}
return $content;
?>

/**
* Extract a specific subtree from a menu tree based on a menu link id (mlid)
*
* @param array $tree
* A menu tree data structure as returned by menu_tree_all_data() or menu_tree_page_data()
* @param int $mlid
* The menu link id of the menu entry for which to return the subtree
* @return array
* The found subtree, or NULL if no entry matched the mlid
*/


function admin_console_menu_get_subtree($tree, $mlid) {
  // Check all top level entries
  foreach ($tree as $key => $element) {
    // Is this the entry we are looking for?
    if ($mlid == $element['link']['mlid']) {
      // Yes, return while keeping the key
      return array($key => $element);
    }
    else {
    // No, recurse to children, if any
      if ($element['below']) {
        $submatch = admin_console_menu_get_subtree($element['below'], $mlid);
        // Found wanted entry within the children?
        if ($submatch) {
          // Yes, return it and stop looking any further
          return $submatch;
        }
      }
   }
}
// No match at all
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: My issue is menu_tree_page_data or menu_tree_all_data returns an empty array for custom menus I have made which do have items. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal adds 'menu-' to the menu name you specify, but doesn't use this on stock menus, so 'primary-links' works for the Primary Links menu.